# Change resource url for Nova resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I've got a model named "Card" but if I use it as Nova Resource, I get an error because it tries to call the "Nova Cards" api instead of my custom resource.

How can avoid id?

Answer (score 7):

`Card` is a reserved name. You can give it a different `uri key` to solve this by overriding the `public static function uriKey()` function